# can't use type=ArmorStand in minecraft 16w38a, is this a bug or an error on my part?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

when I try to use type=ArmorStand in a command in minecraft 16w38a it says `Entity Type 'minecraft:armorstand is invalid'` is this a known bug or just me?

example command i'm using: `/kill @e[type=ArmorStand]` or `/entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand] {}`

Comment: It works if i replace `ArmorStand` with `Ghast` or something, although obv targets that mob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity savegame IDs have been modified for 1.11 to comply with the naming standard for other IDs (such as items and blocks). The IDs are now namespaced (defaulting to `minecraft`), are lowercase, and use underscores where there would be spaces. Some IDs have been completely renamed.

`ArmorStand` is now `minecraft:armor_stand`, or `armor_stand`:

```
/kill @e[type=armor_stand]
```

The wiki lists the new IDs [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values/Entity_IDs).